# What languages/resources did google use to create the "Tokyo Doodle Olympic Game"?

Tags: google-chrome, game-engine

We've all seen google's new Tokyo Olympic game on chrome promoting the Tokyo Olympics. It's a really fun little RPG game. I just wanted to know what resources/languages did they use in order to create the game.

I'm referring to this game that's currently on the browser.

[Doodle Champion Island Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ8Uf.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Doodle that comes on Google home page then those Doodles are created in JavaScript using HTML CSS. Of course they might have used some of JS Libraries.